# Did Frances Coppola tweet about immigration opponents organising the Cologne sex crimes?

Tags: sexual-abuse, media, germany, social-media

Did [Frances Coppola](http://www.forbes.com/sites/francescoppola/), a senior journalist at Forbes, post the following tweet?

[image: Text below]

> @shoerster I bet they did. I suspect anti-immigration people of organising the Cologne
>   sex crimes. Fastest way of getting borders closed.

The screenshot is from a [tweet](https://twitter.com/RitaPanahi/status/685304378836701185) by Rita Panahi, and the allegation was also made in the [Herald Sun](http://www.heraldsun.com.au/news/opinion/rita-panahi/the-sexual-assaults-in-cologne-show-even-the-harshest-facts-must-be-faced/news-story/9486f1775c0cf2be9fe1bbd444ccae67#load-story-comments) (paywalled), a major Australian tabloid newspaper, in a column by Panahi called "The sexual assaults in Cologne show even the harshest facts must be faced" (January 11, 2016):

> Meanwhile Forbes senior journalist Frances Coppola posted a comment
>   alleging a vast conspiracy: “I suspect anti-immigration people of
>   organising the Cologne sex crimes. Fastest way of getting borders
>   closed.”

I also came across an article in the neo-nazi site The Daily Stormer ([Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Daily_Stormer)) [Forbes Journalist: “I Suspect Anti-Immigration ppl of Organising the Cologne Sex Crimes”](http://www.dailystormer.com/forbes-journalist-i-suspect-anti-immigration-ppl-of-organising-the-cologne-sex-crimes/), which has an archive.is link of the alleged tweet. However, archive.is explicitly [denies](http://blog.archive.is/post/130201199536/how-do-end-users-know-that-archived-pages-arent) that it can be trusted not to doctor or alter pages:

> How do end users know that archived pages aren't doctored or altered?
>
> Many pages are altered. Main reason is to remove a popup or login box covering the content.

I'm not that skeptical that some people allege a false-flag attack: for example, this [tweet](https://twitter.com/MoonbeamMelly/status/685465513141645312) and [this one](https://twitter.com/MoonbeamMelly/status/685467371063132160) are non-parodic tweets (favorited and retweeted by antisemites) claiming that Jews masterminded this attack by asylum seekers.

Comment: I do have this person on my following list, do I search for the post and post it as an answer if found, or mods would consider it original research?

Comment: If you can find the tweet at the appropriate point in Sklivvz's conversation,  posting what was its original URL could be useful even if it doesn't currently go anywhere - there might be some way to corroborate it with a 3rd party archive service

Comment: Downvoting this. Because it's about whether one low-level celebrity made one controversial tweet.

Comment: @DJClayworth she's not a celebrity, nor is her journalism about entertainment - as mentioned, she's a journalist at Forbes.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - actually, she's NOT a "senior journalist". Her Forbes page simply says she's a "Contributor". Which makes her non-entity and I admit I fail to see the notability evidence here. Random person saying something random on Twitter.

Comment: @user5341 Panahi states that she's a senior journalist in the paragraph quoted.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - I would believe a person's personal bio page at the newspaper they work for over a twitter user :)

Comment: @user5341 Panahi's newspaper column, not her tweet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Her tweets are now protected so it's hard to say.

However I think I found the preceding and subsequent tweet by her counterpart, the German "management consultant and economist" [Bastian van Rieth](https://twitter.com/shoerster). The dates work and the conversation flows -- the tweet you present can still have been manipulated though.
[image: @Frances_Coppola Neither can a lot of people here - but the right wing press had an immediate knee jerk response]

> @Frances_Coppola Neither can a lot of people here - but the right wing press had an immediate knee jerk response

Then her reply

> @shoerster I bet they did. I suspect anti-immigration people of organising the Cologne sex crimes. Fastest way of getting borders closed.

Then his follow up

> @Frances_Coppola I wouldn't go that far, but they are definitely exploiting the events.

[image: @Frances_Coppola I wouldn't go that far, but they are definitely exploiting the events.]